# Using jQuery to change the color of a part of a text in an option element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using jQuery, can we set a portion of a `<option>` text to certain color? For example:

```
<option>John, Rambo, Indiana, Jones, Morpheus, John, McClane, Forrest, Gump</option>
```

If I want to just change the color of "Morpheus". Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you *meant* option value of a `select` box, there is no easy way or even ***cross-browser solution***. You will have to resort to some custom solution using `LIs` to mimic a customized select box and then you can style it with jquery.

For example, [check out the one option here](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/selectmenu/index.html) that you can customize (add colors, etc) however you like.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see jquery helping you much here, but some plain javascript can do this:

```
"John,Rambo,Indiana,Jones,Morpheus,John,McClane,Forrest,Gump".replace(/Morpheus/gi, "<p style='color:blue'>Morpheus</p>")
```

Comment: Hi it is not just a text it is a text value of a select box. <select>
 <option>John,Rambo,Indiana,Jones,Morpheus,John,McClane,Forrest,Gump</option> 
</select>

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to change the color (using JQuery) while the application is running, you can try something like...

```
<SELECT>
<OPTION>What is your preferred browser?</OPTION>
<OPTION id="b1" style="color:Blue">Explorer 5.5</OPTION>
<OPTION id="r1" style="color:Red">Explorer 6.0</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

Then...use JQuery to change the CSS color for the "b1" or "r1" element...

```
$("#b1").css("color", "#FF0000");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#mySelect option:contains('Morpheus')").css("background-color","red")
```